# How to install tensorflow with virtualenvwrapper on macOS-Sierra

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I need to install *TensorFlow* on macOS-Sierra and I want to use *virtualenvwrapper* for that.
To install *TensorFlow* one could follow the *virtualenv* installation walk-through provided by [TensorFlow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac#installing_with_virtualenv). However, I want to do that with *virtualenvwrapper* that [can be installed like so](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#basic-installation).

Could someone who has experience with this guide me through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper:

```
$pip install virtualenv
$pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Then I would create a directory for my virtualenvs.

```
$mkdir ~/.virtualenvs
```

Then I would update my .bashrc file:

```
#put these lines in your .bashrc file
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Then source .bashrc:

```
$source .bashrc
```

Then create my virtual environment:

```
$mkvirtualenv my-virtual-environment --system-site-packages target-directory
```

To activate the virtual environment and install tensorflow:

```
$workon my-virtual-environment
(my-virtual-environment)$pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

I hope this helps. It's been a while since I've been a regular OSX user. If this doesn't work for you, keep this updated and I might be able to help more.

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful. However when I do

'$pip install virtualenv'

I get 'pip: command not found'.
However I can do pip3 or pip2 (I installed python 3 myself). What do you recommend I do? I don't want to mess up anything with the preinstalled version of python on my mac.

Comment: I installed pip with 'sudo easy_install pip'. Then when I do 'source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh' I get 'No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.'

Comment: It looks like virtualenvwrapper isn't installed to the same path that I put in my directions. You'll have to find the path that it has been installed to, and substitute that path in your .bashrc.

Comment: How can I find out where it gets installed? I do `which virtualenv` which yields `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv`. But `which virtualenvwrapper` does not yield anything. However, I can see that 'virtualenvwrapper.sh` exists in `/usr/local/bin/`.