# Problems when installing virtualenvwrapper in macOS

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I need to install `virtualenvwrapper` on my macOS Sierra to be able to install [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac#installing_with_virtualenv). Previously I had installed Python 3 based on the instructions [here](http://python-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/starting/install3/osx.html) using `Homebrew`.

Now `pip` seemed to be nonexistent (`pip2` and `pip3` worked though), so I did

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Then I followed the instructions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45644224/how-to-install-tensorflow-with-virtualenvwrapper-on-macos-sierra), and when I do

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
No module named virtualenvwrapper virtualenvwrapper.sh:
There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is set properly.
```

I have tried the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507186/python-virtualenv-no-module-named-virtualenvwrapper-hook-loader), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29486113/problems-with-python-and-virtualenvwrapper-after-updating-no-module-named-virtu?rq=1), but no success. I have even tried to install `virtualenvwrapper` with:

```
sudo pip2 install --upgrade virtualenvwrapper
```

and

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade virtualenvwrapper
```

and still I get the same error. Could someone please help me with this issue?

**EDIT:**

I have tried to do lazy loading of the `virtualenvwrapper` like so:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT=/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh
```

Only then I don't get any errors, and I am able to proceed with installing `TensorFlow`. But then every time I open a new terminal `workon` does not work, and I have to do `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh` every time to be able to use `workon`. Even when `workon` is invoked I get a warning/error message as `/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper`.

Could someone help me see what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is simply a hack and not a clean and logical way for solving this but you could edit `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` as root and in the section that is followed by

```
# Locate the global Python where virtualenvwrapper is installed.
```

remove the if/else condition and simply use
`VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="$(command \which python3.5)"` (Change 3.5 to your version) and then `source` the file again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But now I get the following error `-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: line 127: syntax error near unexpected token` ``os.path.normpath'` `-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: line 127: `        `"$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON" -c "import os,sys; sys.stdout.write(os.path.normpath(os.path.expanduser(os.path.expandvars(\"$1\")))+'\n')"'`

Comment: You have a typo! copy and paste line 127 of the file here

Comment: I don't think I have a typo. Even replacing the if/else with just `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="$(command \which python)"` still gives the old initalization of hooks error. :-/

Comment: do you use python3.5?

Comment: I have installed python2.7 and 3.6 with brew.

Comment: I still get the same error

-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: line 123: syntax error near unexpected token `os.path.normpath'
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: line 123: `        "$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON" -c "import os,sys; sys.stdout.write(os.path.normpath(os.path.expanduser(os.path.expandvars(\"$1\")))+'\n')"'

Comment: By the way doing `which python` yields `/usr/bin/python` which I think is the apple's default install of python?

Comment: copy and paste the next lines of `# Locate the global Python where virtualenvwrapper is installed.` here

Comment: `# Locate the global Python where virtualenvwrapper is installed.
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="$(command \which python3.6)”

# Set the name of the virtualenv app to use.
if [ "$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV" = "" ]
then
    VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV="virtualenv"
fi`

Comment: Ops! notice the `”` after `python3.6)` it should be double quotes (`"`).
use `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="$(command \which python3.6)"` instead

Comment: Thank you so much this solved the problem! However, when I open a new terminal and I type `workon` it says `workon: command not found`. Why is that?

Comment: you have to put the source command in your bashrc file.
`'source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: http://exponential.io/blog/2015/02/10/install-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! You are a star! :)